# speed-ups to compute the number of strings over an alphabet that have no repeated substrings of length > 1

Tags: string, algorithm

So it seems no one knows a formula in terms of N for the number of strings over an alphabet of size N that each have no repeated substring of length >= 2. The number of De Bruijn sequences can be used to provide a lower bound. However what if we want to compute the exact number for as large of N as possible? Are there programming tricks (symmetry, etc.) that can be used to compute the number of such strings for decent sized N?

Comment: Must the *forbidden* repetition be immediate / consecutive ? eg in "ABCAB", do you count "AB" as a repetition?

Comment: Sorry that wasn't clear, the forbidden repetitions can be anywhere, e.g. in your example that would count as a forbidden repetition.

Comment: Wouldn't in that case the maximum size of a nonrepeating sequence be around N*N ? (could be ((N-1)*N), I am too lazy to check)

Comment: @wildplasser Yes the length of the strings must be O(N^2), but I'm interested in the total number of strings, not their maximum length. At any rate, brute force counting would break down around N=5 or N=6 without speed-ups.

Comment: Problem smells like Catalan numbers.

Comment: Do overlapping substrings count as repetition? For example, "aa" and "aa" in the string "aaa".

Comment: Yes, overlapping repeated substrings are not allowed either so "aaa" cannot appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious symmetry to exploit is permuting the letter identities to generate only lexicographically minimum representatives. The following Python code uses a recursive search with pruning. It doesn't get very far, so I'm not sure if you think of it as "brute force".

There might be a silver bullet waiting, but I suspect not, in which case pushing N will be like digging a tunnel with a rock hammer.

```
import math

def nonrep(n, s=''):
    a = (ord(min(s)) if s else ord('a'))
    c = ((ord(max(s)) + 1) if s else a)
    total = (math.factorial(n) // math.factorial((n - (c - a))))
    for b in range(a, min((c + 1), (a + n))):
        t = (s + chr(b))
        if (t[(- 2):] not in s):
            total += nonrep(n, t)
    return total
for k in range(1, 12):
    print(nonrep(k))
```

The next step is to memoize by used substrings. The following C++11 code can do N=6 (2131886084545954033) fairly quickly on a machine with a ton of memory.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <unordered_map>

namespace {

static const int kN(6);

long long Count(std::unordered_map<unsigned long long, long long>* memo,
                unsigned long long used,
                int end) {
  auto got(memo->find(used));
  if (got != memo->end()) {
    return got->second;
  }
  long long total(1);
  for (int j(0); j != kN; ++j) {
    unsigned long long bit(1ULL << (j * kN + end));
    if (used < (1ULL << (j * kN)) && j != 0) {
      total += (kN - j) * Count(memo, used | bit, j);
      break;
    } else if ((used & bit) == 0) {
      total += Count(memo, used | bit, j);
    }
  }
  if (total >= 100) {
    (*memo)[used] = total;
  }
  return total;
}
}  // namespace

int main(void) {
  std::unordered_map<unsigned long long, long long> memo;
  std::printf("%lld\n", 1 + kN * Count(&memo, 0, 0));
}
```

The next step after this probably is more symmetry breaking, e.g., by intelligently permuting the letters further to canonize `used`, but I think it's going to be a long way to N=7.